# Qt Compilation with dbus

Tags: qt, compilation, dbus

I am trying to compile qt with dbus but it gives me the following exception. I have installed the dbus version 1.3 in the system and I am using the following configure command. 
Can someone point me as to what should be done.

```
configure -dbus -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -L/usr/local/dbus/lib -ldbus-1 -fast -prefix /home/thwijeth/Software/qt-4.8.1-com-debug -v
```

thank you in advance.

```
qdbus_symbols_p.h:39: fatal error: dbus/dbus.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from qdbusconnection_p.h:51,
             from qdbusconnection.cpp:33:
qdbus_symbols_p.h:39: fatal error: dbus/dbus.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [qdbuserror.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [qdbusconnection.o] Error 1
In file included from qdbusconnectioninterface.cpp:33:
qdbus_symbols_p.h:39: fatal error: dbus/dbus.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [qdbusconnectioninterface.o] Error 1
In file included from qdbusconnection_p.h:51,
             from qdbusintegrator.cpp:33:
qdbus_symbols_p.h:39: fatal error: dbus/dbus.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [qdbusintegrator.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/thwijeth/Software/qt-repo/qt-4.8.1-src/src/dbus'
make: *** [sub-dbus-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

verify if `/usr/include/dbus-1.0` contains a `dbus` directory, if it does not, verify whether `/usr/include/dbus-1.0` contains `dbus.h`, if so you need to create a symbolic link to `dbus-1.0` as `dbus`

`ln -s dbus-1.0 /usr/include/dbus`

and then try to rerun configure.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked fine for me for this missing header. However, I got then a different error `fatal error: dbus/dbus-arch-deps.h: No such file`. I worked around this error by copying this file from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include/dbus` to `/usr/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/`. I don't know why this header was not in the `/usr/include` directory from the beginning. But this is my hack to the problem.

Regards

Comment: in my installation, that file is the only file in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include/dbus so I guess that is on purpose. The name arch-deps also suggests that the file is not cross-platform compatible - I think the proper way to solve this would be to add the parameter -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include